# How can I load a sql "dump" file into sql alchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a large sql dump file ... with multiple `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.  Is there any way to load these all into a SQLAlchemy sqlite database at once.  I plan to use the introspected ORM from `sqlsoup` after I've created the tables.  However, when I use the `engine.execute()` method it complains: `sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.`

Is there a way to work around this issue.  Perhaps splitting the file with a regexp or some kind of parser, but I don't know enough SQL to get all of the cases for the regexp.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Will

EDIT:
Since this seems important ... The dump file was created with a MySQL database and so it has quite a few commands/syntax that sqlite3 does not understand correctly.

Comment: why would you go through sqlalchemy? just load the dump file into the database directly.

Comment: I'm hoping to use the 'in-memory' function of the sqlalchemy/sqlite3

Comment: In memory, in swap, in a scratch DB file, is there any difference?

Comment: An example of the dump syntax would allow a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"or some kind of parser"
I've found MySQL to be a great parser for MySQL dump files :)
You said it yourself: "so it has quite a few commands/syntax that sqlite3 does not understand correctly." Clearly then, SQLite is not the tool for this task.
As for your particular error: without context (i.e. a traceback) there's nothing I can say about it. Martelli or Skeet could probably reach across time and space and read your interpreter's mind, but me, not so much.

Comment: despite your sarcasm this actually what I ended up doing.  I loaded it into a new MySQL database and then dumped the data out into a format that's easier for a SQLite database to read.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL recognized by MySQL and the SQL in SQLite are *quite* different.  I suggest dumping the data of each table individually, then loading the data into equivalent tables in SQLite.

Create the tables in SQLite manually, using a subset of the "CREATE TABLE" commands given in your raw-dump file.